# Why was K-Mart's name changed from the original draft script?

Tags: character, resident-evil-extinction, zoolander

In the original draft script for [*Resident Evil: Extinction*](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/K-Mart) (2007), K-Mart's name was originally supposed to be 'Elizabeth Jane Case'. In the film, however, she explains that she got her nickname because she was found at a K-Mart store.

The main protagonist in the *Resident Evil* films is Alice who is portrayed by actress Milla Jovovich who portrayed a character named Katinka in the 2001 film [*Zoolander*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0196229/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). Katinka refers to another character in the film as "K-Mart", due to her lack of fashion sense.

Quotes from Katinka in *Zoolander*:

- > I suggest you and your K-Mart Jaclyn Smith Collection outfit...
- > Glad you could join us, K-Mart.

etc

---

The name "K-Mart" is not an ordinary everyday name to call a person and it is interesting that Milla Jovovich stars in two separate movies in which characters are called by this name.

**Is the use of calling a character "K-Mart" in two separate films merely a coincidence?**

Given that actress Milla Jovovich is married to the writer of the film, Paul W.S. Anderson in real life, **is there any evidence that she had any influence over the character's name being changed from the original draft script, possibly as a reference to the earlier film?**

Comment: K-Mart is American slang for "*A department store that sells, among other items, notoriously unfashionable/poor quality clothing*"

Comment: Given the incredibly extensive product placement in both films, it wouldn't surprise me if the use of the name K-Mart wasn't a paid feature; https://productplacementblog.com/tag/resident-evil-extinction-2007/ / https://productplacementblog.com/tag/zoolander-2001/

Comment: Really?  K-Mart could afford product placement? lol

Comment: @Valorum Really? K-Mart are going to pay to have their name used as a dergoratory term?

Comment: @Darren - It may astound you to learn that product placement isn't always positive; https://www.martinlindstrom.com/negative-product-placement/ You can also pay to place an opponent's product in an unfavourable light.

Comment: @steelersquirrel: I think you're confusing the bottom line of the company with the store price of its products.

Comment: @Darren: Negative attention is still better than no attention, from a marketing perspective (and restricting it to a tempered form of negativity, i.e. not the worst of the worst). When you're a store that prides itself on selling low-cost products, being called cheap by an elitist rich person does not actually harm your reputation towards your intended customer base. If anything, it reinforces it.

Comment: I thought that kmart went bankrupt

Comment: @steelersquirrel - In 2002 they did one of those bullsh*t bankruptcies where they screw over their investors and debtors, then emerge as basically the same company except with no debts. Then they did exactly the same again 20 years later.